# Is it possible to build an html webpage completely out of javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to build an html webpage entirely out of javascript? Would you need anchors like some div elements to organize things?

Comment: No, you can't show anything in a browser without HTML. You can create that HTML with JS, though.

Comment: I am saying if you could take the entire thing and use javascript to build the entire html file on load

Comment: You'd still need a script tag, that's HTML too.

Comment: Very good point. Thank you

Comment: At a minimum you need a `script` tag (plus the HTML boilerplate - `DOCTYPE`, `html`, `head`, `body` etc. - to be properly valid).

Comment: React comes pretty close to being able to build entire web apps with practically no HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cant build an entire website out of javascript BUT if the question is can you build the website using javascript into HTML, CSS, etc yes. At the end of the day HTML and CSS is just text you can easily form these files from javascript.

Comment: I think the answer is YES you can have no HTML file and still have a webpage. In fact you will need **not** to create an HTML file using JS also. There are so many template engines out there like hbs, ejs, pug, asp., etc etc

Comment: @KartikMalik The template engines are another story, they're hardly scoped to JavaScript only. Of course you can write a .js file and serve that from a Node.js server, but a browser still can't show anything if the loaded file doesn't contain HTML.